# Clang thread safety analysis and thread roles

Tags: c++, thread-safety, clang

The clang thread safety analysis [docs](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSafetyAnalysis.html) and [paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42958.pdf) hint that it's possible to indicate that specific functions be only called by specific threads. From the paper:

```
#include "ThreadRole.h"

ThreadRole InputThread;
ThreadRole GUIThread;

class Widget {
public :
    virtual void onClick() REQUIRES(InputThread);
    virtual void draw() REQUIRES(GUIThread);
};

class Button : public Widget {
public :
    void onClick() override {
        depressed = true;
        draw() ; // WARNING!
    }
};
```

However, neither doc indicates how you actually annotate `ThreadRole` to make this happen. What does `ThreadRole` have to look like to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Relevant:
https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/sei_blog/2014/10/thread-safety-analysis-in-c-and-c.html

`typedef int __attribute__((capability("role"))) ThreadRole;
ThreadRole FlightControl, Logging;
void acquire(ThreadRole R) __attribute__((acquire_capability(R))) __attribute__((no_thread_safety_analysis)) {}
void release(ThreadRole R) __attribute__((release_capability(R))) __attribute__((no_thread_safety_analysis)) {}`

...